# Comprobar que no esté vacío array checkboxs Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

Tengo un **formulario** con una serie de **accesorios** para un hotel, y los almaceno en un array llamado **accesorios[].**

El código es:

```
<label for="accesorios">Accesorios:</label><br/>
<label for="secador">Secador:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="secador" name="accesorios[]" value="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="calefaccion">Calefaccion: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="calefaccion" name="accesorios[]" value="2" />
<br/><br/>
<label for="jacuzzi">Jacuzzi: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="jacuzzi" name="accesorios[]" value="3" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="tv">TV: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="tv" name="accesorios[]" value="4" />
<br/><br/>
<label for="internet">Internet: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="internet" name="accesorios[]" value="5" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="microondas">Microondas: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="microondas" name="accesorios[]" value="6" />
```

**¿Cómo compruebo que debe marcar al menos un checkbox desde Javascript o jQuery?**

**Código Javascript:**

```
function validar_formulario_cabana(){
    var nombre, descripcion, precio, imagen, accesorios;

    nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    descripcion = document.getElementById("descripcion").value;
    precio = document.getElementById("precio").value;
    imagen = document.getElementById("precio").value;
    accesorios = document.getElementById("anadir_cabana").checkbox; //Array.

    var contar = 0; //Variable que lleva la cuenta de los checkbox pulsados.

    for (var x=0; x<accesorios.length; x++) {
        if (accesorios[x].checked) {
            contar = contar + 1;
        }
    }

    if(nombre=="" || descripcion=="" || precio=="" || imagen==""){
        alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios.");
        return false;
    }else if(nombre.length>50){
        alert("El nombre debe tener menos de 51 carácteres.");
        document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
        document.getElementById("nombre").value="";
        return false;
    }else if(descripcion.length>200){
        alert("La descripción superan los 200 carácteres de límite.");
        document.getElementById("descripcion").focus();
        document.getElementById("descripcion").value="";
        return false;
    }else if(precio.value>99999){
        alert("El precio de la cabaña no está en el rango establecido.");
        document.getElementById("precio").focus();
        document.getElementById("precio").value="";
        return false;
    }else if(contar<1){
        alert("¡Debes activar al menos un accesorio!");
        document.getElementById("precio").focus();
        document.getElementById("precio").value="";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` se usa seleccionar por nombre de etiqueta, porque tienes "accesorios" si no es una etiqueta? Usas una libreria?

Comment: Utiliza las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador que estés utilizando. Por ejemplo tienes `getElemetById('nombre')` pero no tienes ningún id con 'nombre'.

Comment: En tu html solo tienes checkboxes y en el js tienes text inpus o areas.

Comment: Cuando quieres hace `document.getElementById("nombre").value;` marca error ya que no hay un id "nombre".

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo intentas realizar si el js no hace referencia al html que muestras. La respuesta de abajo funciona para validar que haya por lo menos un checkbox activado, sólo te faltaría validar lo demás.

Comment: @loki Borremos los comentarios porque el usuario que entre a ver si la respuesta/pregunta le ayudan se va a liar... Creo que la pregunta está muy bien formulada y entendible respecto a los botones.

Comment: Entiendo lo de los checkbox. En ese caso utiliza la respuesta debajo. En caso de encontrar un error, por favor muestralo o proporciona todo el código de lo contrario no es posible reproducir el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, puedes usar querySelectorAll para que te devuelva un nodelist de los que están marcados, y si es mayor de 0 ejecutar tú código.

```js
 function validar_formulario_cabana() {
    const accesorios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'); 
    if(accesorios.length <= 0){
      console.log("no se encuentra ningún checkbox marcado")
      return;
    }
  // tu código
  }
```

```html
  <label for="accesorios">Accesorios:</label>
  <br/>
  <label for="secador">Secador:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="secador" name="accesorios[]" value="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="calefaccion">Calefaccion: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="calefaccion" name="accesorios[]" value="2" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label for="jacuzzi">Jacuzzi: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="jacuzzi" name="accesorios[]" value="3" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="tv">TV: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="tv" name="accesorios[]" value="4" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label for="internet">Internet: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="internet" name="accesorios[]" value="5" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="microondas">Microondas: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="microondas" name="accesorios[]" value="6" />
  <button onclick="validar_formulario_cabana()">comprobar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Aquí tienes una funcion:**

```
var check = e => Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(e)).filter(cur => cur.checked).length > 0;
```

- Explicacion: Crea un array a través de un objeto iterable, luego lo filtro con el método filter, cuya condición es que el nodo se encuentre chequeado. Si el array devuelto tiene longitud mayor a 0 es porque almenos 1 elemento se chequeó.

**Y la podrás usar así:**

```js
var check = e => Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(e)).filter(cur => cur.checked).length > 0;


chec.onclick = function() {
 if(!check("input")) alert("No se ha chequeado un checkbox");
 else alert("Se ha chequeado almenos un input");
};
```

```html
Solo rojo: <input type="checkbox">
Solo verde <input type="checkbox">

<input type="button" value="Comprobar chequeados" id=chec />
```